# Social login only with ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, session-cookies, claims-based-identity

My applications needs to support Google+ login *only*. No internal users in a database or anything extra. I was able to configure the stuff so that the following action is hit by Google with identity information:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        ExternalLoginInfo loginInfo = await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
        // what do I do here ?????????
    }
```

My understanding is that I need to somehow store claims returned by Google into a session cookie but I don't know what to do. Should I convert `ExternalLoginInfo` into `IPrincipal` first? How do I have the principal instantiated on the subsequent requests?

My initialization code is:

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
    });

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // bla-bla-bla
    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleAuthOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any of the Identity tables, I don't think Identity is a good fit for you. It persists the claims and logins in the database, and I don't think there's much you can do about that.

In this one narrow scenario, it is actually probably better if your roll-your-own. Just follow the Google API docs and implement their login manually. You're essentially outsourcing all the authentication at this point, so there aren't a whole lot of security implications from not relying on a more standard authentication framework like Identity. You may even be able to find a Nuget package that just does Google Auth.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything.

1. They authenticated on the client side (which gave them a cookie), then
2. You set up Owin middleware correctly for google on your backend.

This has taken care of everything.
I believe that the Owin middleware does not go and automatically register users into a database for you.
Depending on the scopes you asked for on the front end, it will be able to give you some details of the user which are in the principle. (MS converts them to Claims for you).